# Determination of temperature from electromagnetic emissions

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, temperature

The actual measured radiation intensity at different frequencies varies significantly from the ideal theoretical Planck curve. For example, here is the result of a typical laboratory measurement at 1100C for a given material:

[image]

Is there a theory or recommended method for inferring from such measurements temperature in a way that copes with the irregularity of the measured spectrum?

Comment: Have you tried a numerical integration scheme rather than an analytical model fit?